# Smith Number,Timeout Error for large input Optimization

Tags: java, math, timeout, mathematical-optimization

i wrote this code to check if a no is smith no or not on hackerrank.
A Smith number is a composite number, the sum of whose digits is the sum of the digits of its prime factors obtained as a result of prime factorization (excluding ). The first few such numbers are 4,22,27.
This code works perfectly but gives timeout error for input = 2050918644.
Now can you tell me how can i edit this code and make sure that it doesnt give me the timeout error

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
static int sumD(int a){
        int sum=0;
    while(a>0)
    {
        int rem=0;
        rem=a%10;
        sum=sum+rem;
        a=a/10;


    }
    return sum;}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        int s=0;
        int temp=x;
        for(int i=2;i<x;i++)
        {
            while(temp%i==0)
            {  s=s+ sumD(i);
            temp=temp/i;}
        }
        if(sumD(x)==s)
            {
            System.out.println(1);

        }
        else
            System.out.println(0);
        }

}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JavaScript -- JavaScript question tag removed.

Comment: You should use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: i dont even have a clue about bigInteger

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop all the way from `2` to `x`. Worst case scenario your number is `some prime number * 2`, so you will cover all the prime factors doing half the job (Since prime number itself cannot be Smith number). So your `for` loop will look like this:

```
for(int i=2;i<=x/2;i++)
{
    while(temp%i == 0){
        s=s+ sumD(i);
        temp=temp/i;
    }
}
```

This works much faster and may or may not be sufficient for you, **but** this is **far** from being optimal. If you need something faster, please read about prime factorization algorithms using sieve, Pollard's rho algorithm etc.

Also note that if you want to use numbers higher than `2^31-1`, you need to use something else than `int` (at least `long`).